# Looking into bass traps

Tags: bass, room-treatment

I'm looking into getting some bass traps for my tiny apartment room. Has anyone heard of The Foam Factory company? They sell foam bass traps and my budget is pretty low. I was thinking about putting one or two in each corner of the room. What do you guys think? 
http://www.thefoamfactory.com/acousticfoam/bassbroad.html

Comment: I'm no expert, but when I was looking for bass traps, I read on multiple places that foam doesnt do the trick for bass - unless you get it really, really thick, and then it gets expensive. You want rockwool in wood frames. Can easily build them yourself, there's also companies that do it for you (gik acoustics is one). Check Gearslutz and Google on how to build these things yourself :) 

Answer (score 1):

I can't say anything about bass traps but I have outfitted my bedroom 16/18 foot (????) with OC panels about 9 of them and in the corners (incidentally where my speakers are pointing) i have them hung "caddy corner."

The room is carpeted and the freq response in the room is nice after the panels and this severely helped with bass management as well.  I could stuff blankets behind the corner panels if I had the time/money or use foam and it would probably cut down on the bass a little bit.

It is incredibly important to be working in a treated room and anything that you can do towards this, you will notice and appreciate in the end.

The 9 OC panels after hanging and wrapping cost me around 250-300 dollars.  Over a couple months, that was do'able for me.

Comment: @Chris The only problem is I can't hang anything that's going to permanently damage the wall since I'm moving out of the apt. in July. I was thinking about getting adhesive but I doubt that would work for these panels you're speaking of. 

Comment: You can try making stands out of wood/poles/mic stands or material from Craigslist, and hanging the panels from there.

Comment: As for mounting bass traps in a rented flat - don't use adhesive :) Just hang em like you would a painting/photo, i.e. have basstraps in a frame. This will only leave 1 or a few small holes which can easily be filled when you leave the flat

Answer (score 0):

Build them yourself.

There are heaps of tutorials out there and can be done fairly cheap. Make triangle floor stand wedges and then no need to attach them to the walls. You can also move them around to tune your room.

Most of your issue will be around the corners of the room. The high end reflections will the killer for the centre of your walls and will need something different to diffuse them.

Also look at what is on your floor. If you apartment is a wooden floor then put a rug/thick matt down. Even put some rubber under your DAW table and sub-woofer.

Good luck.